# Как удалить скобки из input?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!

Использую masked-inputs при регистрации и авторизации на сайте.
Логин имеет форму - 7 (888) 888-88888.
Как сделать так, чтобы в БД заносились только цифры без пробелов, тире и скобок?

Спасибо за любую помощь!

Answer (score 5):

```
var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
// все кроме цифр удалится из логина
login = login.replace(/[^\d]+/g, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно заносить в бд, то это лучше делать на стороне сервера

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $str);
```